# useEffect causing error message to pop up multiple times

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks, use-effect

I have a selector that retrieves the errors in the state. It is just a boolean.

```
const error = useSelector((state: IAppState) => {
  return state?.error?.securityProfileError
})
```

`True` means there is an error.
`False` means there is no error.

Here is my code.

```
const error = useSelector((state: IAppState) => {
  return state?.error?.securityProfileError
})

useEffect(() => {
  if (error) showToast(lang.messages.errors.profile)
})
```

As you can see, inside `useEffect` hook, I check if there is an error, and if there is, I show a toast.

Here is the problem.

Since `useEffect` gets called multiple times, and `error` can remain `true`, I get multiple toast messages. I just want one.

However, I **cannot** use `useEffect` like this ...

```
  useEffect(() => {
    // do stuff
  }, []);
```

because it only fires once, and if `error` starts off as `false` but then goes to `true`, my toast never gets to show, because ... well, the `useEffect` fires only once.

So, I'm not sure what to do here.

Curious to hear your suggestions.

Comment: Have you tried adding `error` as a dependency of `useEffect`?

Comment: I totally forgot that you could pass elements into the array argument of useEffect. This worked. Thank you.

Comment: @NikhilBhaskar If this project was created with create-react-app then the linter should have been set up to give you a warning about [missing dependencies](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14920) of the effect when you give it an empty dependency array. It can even auto fix it for you in vs code.